# How do I completely turn off my touchbar?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I have owned a 2019 16" MacBook since it came out.

A couple of months ago my touchbar started out of nowhere to show vertical green lines all across it, rendering it almost unusable. Since it is out of warranty and I am not some sort of money printer, I decided to go to the best unauthorized service provider in my area, but to no success. I either had to replace the whole casing which would have cost me an arm and a leg or to have them replace the touchbar for a quite reasonable price.

Sadly, all the parts that they and I ordered seemed to come broken, either not turning on at all or showing green/red lines, so I've been stuck with an ugly green touchbar ever since.

Recently, I have tried to turn it off completely, but to no success. Do any of you know any other solution to this other than opening the laptop and unplugging the ribbon cable?